# Google App maker Drive picker

Tags: google-app-maker

We have drive picker in the widgets panel. We added the drive picker in our canvas when we tried to set the bindings for SelectedDocUrl and SelectedDocName the binding popup does not shows the **properties** where we can use the file properties in our requirement.

But in the sample projects it is showing, for the drive picker sample project and document approval sample project it is showing other than that it is not showing any other apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In those samples page [Custom Properties](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#custom_properties) are used. To use these properties you need to define them manually first:
[image: Page custom properties]

But most likely in real-life application you'll need to bind Drive Picker's properties to some datasource item fields(so be sure, that your Drive Picker widget inherits right datasource).

Comment: Thanks pavel. In the example custom properties are created, Will it work if I multiple items has been selected.

Comment: You need to do some scripting in 'onDocumentSelect' Drive Picker event to handle multiple files. It worth separate question, so feel free to ask if you have a need.

Comment: Sure I will ask  a separate question